# Symfony translation inside validation won't work

Tags: validation, symfony, translation

If I try to use translations inside validation like described here
http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/symfony2-translating-validator-messages/

I get always

```
not.blank.username
```

as output on Error. It seems like symfony didn't find the message-translation. I placed all my translationfiles inside app/ressources/translations and they are named as

```
messages.de.yml
....
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to place the translationfiles insde each Bundle?

Kind regards

EDIT: Problem ist clear and fixed, but when I  try to use "MinLength" I get an strange error:

```
Attempted to load class "MinLength" from namespace 
"Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints" in /var/www/symfony/webprojekt/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/Loader/AbstractLoader.php line 64. 
Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?
```

I already included

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MinLength;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\MaxLength;
```

AM I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To translate validation messages you need to create files with the following name structure inside `translations` folder:

```
validators.LANG.yml
```

Also, you can check in your `config.yml`, inside `framework`, if exists the translator:

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: %locale% }
```

This is required.

Comment: Yeah, thats it. I didn't know that I have to place those messages in an seperated file. I only get some yml errors with the german special characters like ÄÖÜäöü, even with UTF-8.

Comment: Another problem is the usage ob "MinLength" maybe someone cann tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer applies to using the magical default translation domain for the validator config.  You can also override this in `config/packages/validator.yaml`

```
framework:
    validation:
        enable_annotations: true
        translation_domain: 'validations'
```

Then in `translations/` make a file **validations.LANG.yaml**, for example `translations/validations.en.yaml`.  You don't need to do this but sometimes it's better to explicitly set these magical bit and know where they're coming from.